# My php tweet authenticates but is not posting

Tags: php, twitter

What is the purpose of:

```
if (isset($_GET['count']) && is_numeric($_GET['count'])) {
    $count = $_GET['count'];
} else {
    $count= 20;
}
```

It returns 20 and the tweet never posts.

Any ideas why?

Comment: If the user making the request has asked for a specific count and that requested value is a number, then the code uses that count. Otherwise, the count defaults to 20.

Comment: $_GET['count'] checks if there is either a "?count=XYZ" or "&count=XYZ" part in your URL, either by submitting a form with method="GET" or by manually writing it to the URL, and if XYZ has a numeric value. If not, count is set to 20 (default value).

Comment: What is the purpose this count? It returns 20 and echos the tweet string 20 times and never posts

Comment: What is the purpose of the count? Shouldn't it return 1? Is this why it never posts?

Comment: $requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user']))  {
  $user = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", '', $_GET['user']);
}else {
   $user  = "@DailyBirdBreath";
}

Comment: echo "$getfield\n";?screen_name=@DailyBirdBreath&count=1&tweet_mode=extended

Comment: <h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>Sorry, that page does not exist.</em></p>

Comment: This is probably my problem. Any idea why?